# MSSQL - How to get addition for aggregated value for grouped select query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a select query that results table with values like:

```
+--------+-----------+-------------+----------------+-------------+----------------+
|SystemId|EquipmentId|ActiveStageId|ActiveStageOrder|StageStatusId|StageStatusOrder|
+--------+-----------+-------------+----------------+-------------+----------------+
|   1    |    288    |     1       |       1        |      3      |       3        |
|   1    |    355    |     1       |       1        |      7      |       6        |
|   1    |    80     |     2       |       3        |      1      |       1        |
|   1    |    288    |     4       |       2        |      1      |       1        |
|   2    |    412    |     4       |       2        |      2      |       2        |
|   2    |    54     |     2       |       3        |      4      |       5        |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
etc...
```

And I need group this result by **SystemId** and select: **SystemId**, count of **EquipmentId**, **ActiveStageId** for grouped System with minimal value of **ActiveStageOrder** and **StageStatusId** for previous **ActiveStageId** with mininal value if **StageStatusOrder**.
I know how to get grouped table with aggregated values *min()* and *count()*:

```
SELECT SystemId, COUNT(EquipmentId) as EqupmentCount,
       MIN(ActiveStageOrder) as ActiveStageOrder
FROM [dbo].[Table]
GROUP BY SystemId
```

But how can I get **ActiveStageId** for min **ActiveStageOrder** and **StageStatusId** for min **StageStatusOrder**? Need to get result for above example:

```
+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|SystemId|EqupmentCount|ActiveStageId|StageStatusId|
+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|   1    |      4      |     1       |      3      |
|   2    |      2      |     4       |      1      |
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: What's the expected result if two rows have the same min StageStatusOrder value, but different StageStatusId values?

Comment: @jarlh Suppose that equal StageStatusId's always have same StageStatusOrder value. But ActiveStageId may have diiferent values of StageStatusId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like below by using window function

```
   with cte as (
      select SystemId,count(*) over(partition by SystemId) as EqupmentCount,
       FIRST_VALUE(ActiveStageId)over(partition by SystemId order by ActiveStageOrder) ActiveStageId,
       FIRST_VALUE(StageStatusId) over( partition by SystemId order by ActiveStageOrder,StageStatusOrder) StageStatusId
     from table_name
       ) select distinct * from cte
```

Comment: Think that should be not **min(ActiveStageId)** and **min(StageStatusId)** but **FIRST_VALUE(ActiveStageId)** in case when one _ActiveStageId>ActiveStageOrder_ and other _ActiveStageId<ActiveStageOrder_

Comment: In your function FIRST_VALUE of **StageStatusId** will be selected over all SystemId. And for _SystemId=1_ StageStatusId will be 1. But **StageStatusId** should be taken over SystemId and then minimal **ActiveStageOrder** and for _SystemId=1_ should be equal 3

Comment: It is worked if add to `over(partition by SystemId order by StageStatusOrder)` addition sort with ActiveStageOrder: `over(partition by SystemId order by ActiveStageOrder, StageStatusOrder)`